# A printer's imp has run amok

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, cryptic-clues

*A printer's imp has run amok

distorting clues but with some luck

you'll spy the hidden seams whereat

the devil’s work can be turned back.*

1. Feral Ulysses S. Grant keeps the troops aroused (6)
2. A giant horrifies Frankenstein’s monster (5)
3. Superstitious people consider finding a penny or seeing a shooting star to be greens (4)
4. After speaking with a materialist, I began to wonder whether the mists... (5)
5. Secret society attacked by rider (5)
6. Moon my side (5)
7. Bets make it hard for investors to profit (7)

*Now clues are solved, it’s time you know

a secret’s found in what he stole.

The chosen glyphs arranged with grace

reveal the hellspawn’s hiding place.*

[image]

Comment: Printer's Devil Clues? Oh Dear!

Comment: With no checked letters, to boot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Feral Ulysses S. Grant keeps the troops aroused (6)

> F**oxy Gen**eral Ulysses S. Grant keeps the troops aroused
>  OXYGEN - E

2. A giant horrifies Frankenstein’s monster (5)

> A giant hor**de ter**rifies Frankenstein’s monster (5)
>  DETER - D
>  Solved by Gareth

3. Superstitious people consider finding a penny or seeing a shooting star to be greens (4)

> Superstitious people consider finding a penny or seeing a shooting star to be gre**at om**ens (4)
>  ATOM - T

4. After speaking with a materialist, I began to wonder whether the mists... (5)

> After speaking with a materialist, I began to wonder whether the m**ind ex**ists... (5)
>  INDEX - I

5. Secret society attacked by rider (5)

> Secret society attacked by ri**val or**der (5)
>  VALOR - L

6. Moon my side (5)

> Mo**st are** on my side (5)
>  STARE - S
>  Solved by Sp3000

7. Bets make it hard for investors to profit (7)

> B**ear mark**ets make it hard for investors to profit (7)
>  EARMARK - A

And of course, the (printer's) devil is...

> in the DETAILS

Comment: The remaining 'odd' words seem to be giant, rider and moon

Comment: Could be "horrifies" rather than "giant". E.g., SETER is a word, albeit a very obscure one, and that would yield "A giant horse terrifies ...". (I don't think this is likely to be the intended answer. But something like it might be.)

Comment: @Gareth Ha! "Horse" was my first thought as well.

Comment: HOURI (-> URITE) works too. Or HOSTA (-> STATE). I wouldn't expect Frankenstein's monster to be quite so easily terrified, though.

Comment: The moon one seems like it could have a lot of potential answers, best I have is MO(ST ARE) ON though...

Comment: D'oh! HORDE, DETER, TERRIFIES.

Comment: (I confess, I used a computer. And now I feel so stupid.)

Comment: So unless I've slipped up, if Sp3000's conjecture is right -- which I bet it is -- then we have EDTILSA. That makes DILATES but that's no use. What else?

Comment: I'm thinking the final answer could be CITADEL.

Comment: Ooooh, that sounds good. But then the moon one needs to begin with C, right?

Comment: Actually on second though, it must be DETAILS...

Comment: Yes yes yes yes.

Comment: So Sp3000 is right with STARE and we're done, right?