# Oh, woe is me, the creature's back

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, no-computers, cryptic-clues

*Oh, woe is me, the creature's back

to give me certain heart attack!

He's plucking words and shifting glyphs.

What sort of devilry is this?*

1. I love the gates of hell; I’m kind of a rod (6)
2. The apple shave already bed (6)
3. I'm not afraid of going without food, but I do first (5)
4. Carding is easier than growing potatoes (6)
5. Only the worn are permitted entry to Valhalla (5)
6. The party was lame so sever hem left (5)
7. Marsh as an obit (5)
8. Wouldn’t you rather have the faux fur? Think... (6)

*But you, my puzzler, [once before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48955/a-printers-imp-has-run-amok),

helped me reverse the demon's chore.

So solve again the clues and mend

this time the name of Satan's friend.*

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking the name of the friend is printer :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are all

> printer's devilry clues. Instead of standard cryptics, these are sensible phrases that have had a word removed and the rest of the words respaced.

1.

> I love the gates of hell; I’m kind of a Ro**din ner**d

2.

> The apples have already be**en core**d *(found by Matt)*

3.

> I'm not afraid of going without food, but I do f**ear th**irst

5.

> Only the wor**thy me**n are permitted entry to Valhalla *(found by Matt)*

6.

> The party was lame so sever**al of t**hem left

7.

> Mars has an o**val or**bit *(found by Will)*

8.

> Wouldn't you rather have the faux fur th**an the m**ink? *(found by Will)*

The final answer, obtained by rearranging the red letters, is:

> ADVOCATE

Comment: You never put 7 and 8 in your answer

Answer (score 8):

2.

> ENCORE
>  The apples have already be**en core**d

4.

> ROTTEN (Thanks to @Techidiot in TSL) 
>  Car**rot ten**ding is easier than growing potatoes

5.

> THYME
>  Only the wor**thy me**n are permitted entry to Valhalla

7.

> VALOR
>  Mars has an o**val or**bit

8.

> ANTHEM
>  Wouldn’t you rather have the faux fur th**an the m**ink?